# Getting all accounts with at least 3 projects, and joining account details

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query to get all the accounts with at least 3 projects.

```
SELECT   
        accounts.id,
        accounts.name,
        COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb) as count
FROM    accounts_project_1_c 
LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts_project_1accounts_ida = accounts.id
LEFT JOIN project ON accounts_project_1project_idb = project.id
LEFT JOIN project_cstm ON id_c = project.id

GROUP BY accounts_project_1accounts_ida
HAVING COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb) >= 3
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Where `accounts` is the account table, `project` the project one, and `project_cstm` a table containing more information about projects

This request returns me 153 results.

But now, I would like to get the contact linked to an account. If it exists several contacts, I don't really care, I just want one.

```
SELECT   
        accounts.id,
        accounts.name,
        contacts.first_name,
        contacts.last_name,
        contacts.phone_mobile,
        contacts.phone_work,
        COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb) as count

FROM    accounts_project_1_c 

LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts_project_1accounts_ida = accounts.id
LEFT JOIN project ON accounts_project_1project_idb = project.id
LEFT JOIN project_cstm ON id_c = project.id
LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ON accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
LEFT JOIN contacts ON accounts_contacts.contact_id = contacts.id

GROUP BY accounts_project_1accounts_ida
HAVING COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb) >= 3
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This request returns 173 results.

I don't really get it, using `left join` it should not add any row right?

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `HAVING` to be:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT accounts_project_1project_idb) >= 3
```

You probably want that in the `SELECT` as well.

Comment: Seems to be working. Damn I really should take some SQL lessons!
Thanks a lot Gordon, I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.